# Unlock Windows (Ctrl+Alt+Del combo) through Guacamole JS Session

Tags: reactjs, windows, guacamole

I use `gacamole-common-js` to interact with VMs in a React project.

To unlock Windows VMs I have to send the Ctrl+Alt+Del combo to be able to enter my password.

I need something like Virtualbox's `Insert Ctrl+Alt+Del` button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (React) code :

```js
const handleUnlockWindows = () => {
        guacRef.current.sendKeyEvent(1, 0xFFE3); // Ctrl
        guacRef.current.sendKeyEvent(1, 0xFFE9); // Alt
        guacRef.current.sendKeyEvent(1, 0xFFFF); // Delete
    };
```

`guacRef` is my Guacamole.Client object.

The keysyms code are from the [Guacamole source code](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/0.9.0/guacamole-common-js/symbols/src/src_main_webapp_modules_Keyboard.js.html).

The sendKeyEvent function takes two arguments. The first one is a boolean indicating if the key is pressed (1 = pressed; 0 = released). The second one is the keysym to be sent.